# Python3 import script as library - , but this library cannot access imported libraries from main script

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-packaging

my question actually is quite simple.

I have a main.py, that imports several modules.

Due to complexity I want to move some functions to sub-scripts that I import as a library from the relative sub folder "lib"

That is all working fine.

The issue is, that the imported library from the sub folder "lib" also requires libraries imported in the main.py.

Is there away to avoid importing everything in any script again and instead use the library from the main.py, where I import all just once?

I do not actually care for any isolation. I would even prefer, if all scripts and variables are virtually running as if part of main.py, whithout making the main.py huge and unreadable.

Reason: I have a login handler, that needs to be in a sub library, that will print debug messages in color. That is using a library. I want to avoid to import the color library in all other libraries, that print with color. This would be to much of a mess.

This issue also correlates to other functions and libraries of course.

More visual example:

```
folder/
|-- main.py (needs all *.py from ./library/)
|-- library/
    |-- login.py (needs color.py and more2.py for example
    |-- color.py
    |-- more.py  (needs color.py and more3.py for example)
    |-- more2.py (needs color.py and more.py for example)
    |-- more3.py (needs color.py, more.py and more2.py for example)
```

I really want to avoid to import each library manually in each script. I just want to pass everything from `main.py`, maybe even at one time from `./library/importlibs.py`

Can this be achieved in a nice and readable way?

Edit:

As a reproducible example is required, just use this:

main folder contains:

- main.py
- subfolder "library"

subfolder "library" contains:

- color.py
- login.py

main.py contains:

```
debug = True

import requests
import getpass # to get censored input in console for password
import #...other pip modules

libdir = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__))),"library")
sys.path.append(libdir) # adding the library path, so I can import modules easier

import login # comming from sys.path[len(sys.path)-1), which is "./library"
import color # comming from sys.path[len(sys.path)-1), which is "./library"

#...

session = login.login()
```

Now rough content of "./library/login.py":

```
def login():
username = getinput(color.green+"Enter your username"+color.reset)
if debug:
   print("Debug - Username entered:", username)
password = getpass.getpass(color.red+"Now enter your password"+color.reset)
if debug: 
   print("Debug - Password entered:", password)
return [username, password]
```

It is easy to see, that the library `color` and the library `getpass`, which are loaded from main.py are not available in `./library/login.py`

How can I pass loaded libraries (all of them!) into an imported script? That is my issue. Also the global variable debug is not set in this script as it was in main.py, which will also throw an error.

I do not want to use something like:

`session = login.login(color, gepass, debug, blah_library, globals())`

This would defeat the point of making it more readable considerably.

The only acceptable solution would be:

`session = login.login(A) # A is a placeholder for everything from the script`

Comment: 'sub folder "lib"' - Do you actually mean 'sub folder "library"'? What does this have to do with pip? Sorry, but I don't find the question simple at all. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I want to use pip and non-pip modules from main.py in a sub-script (sub-module). I added a better example. It is however only pseudo-code, as mine is already way to large

Comment: Whether packages and modules were *pip*-installed or not, should not matter. -- Anyway, it feels to me like you are trying to make your life more complicated than necessary here, and write code against best practices. -- I do not understand why you need the `sys.path` manipulation, this is usually a red flag. -- Personally I try to follow these rules for import-related issues: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: It does not matter, how I import my module. My question is, how an import can be used in other modules. The provided link also does not help with that, nor does it give a specific example to whatever it means without actually substatiation. neither PyLint nor PEP matters for me. These standards only help to write 5 lines of code as 500 lines with a complex folder and file structure and "professional programmers" will call this best practice. I do not care for such complex nonsense. Had to be said at one time. So, can the Modules all be passed like with 1 single global variable, or not?